# How to remove an element from an array and then shift other elements over?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, sorting

My problem is with the last function, print_valid_data. I'm supposed to delete the second minimum value from array `A[]`. After the value is deleted the elements in the array need to be shifted over, with the last open spot in the array to be empty. What I did in my function was skip over it, and print out what was left. How would I got about doing it by deletion and then shifting?

Side note:  The Var.h is a file only with the data "const int NUM = 10" could be subject to change, it's for the index of the array. The "data.txt" file has some integers (the program accounts for >10 numbers or <10 numbers) that are read in with the `Load_file_to_array` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Var.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Load_File_To_Array(int A[], string filename, int size);
int Get_2nd_Smallest(int A[], int size);
void Print_valid_data(int A[], int SecondMin, int size);

int main()
{
    int A[NUM];
    int size = NUM;
    int SecondMin = 0;
    string filename = "Data.txt";

    Load_File_To_Array(A, filename, size);
    Get_2nd_Smallest(A, size);
    Print_valid_data(A, SecondMin, size);

    cout << endl;

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

void Load_File_To_Array(int A[], string filename, int size)
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);

    cout << "The array is: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        if (infile.eof())
        break;

        infile >> A[i]; 
        cout << A[i] << ", ";
    }

    return;
}

int Get_2nd_Smallest(int A[], int size)
{
    int Min = A[0];
    int SecondMin = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        if (Min > A[i])
            Min = A[i];
    }

    //Exchange-sort to sort the array in descending order
    int j, k;
    int counter;
    for (j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
    {
        for (k = (j + 1); k < size; k++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[k])
            {
                counter = A[j];
                A[j] = A[k];
                A[k] = counter;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int n = (NUM - 1); n > -1; n--)
    {
        SecondMin = A[n];
        if (SecondMin >= 0)
        {
            SecondMin = A[n - 1];
            break;
        }
        else;
    }

    cout << endl << "The minimum number is: " << Min << endl;
    cout << "The second smallest integer is: " << SecondMin << endl;

    return SecondMin;
}

void Print_valid_data(int A[], int SecondMin, int size)
{
    cout << "The new array is: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] != SecondMin)
        {
            cout << A[i] << ", ";
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Well a quick and dirty way would be to grab the index of the second smallest number and then iterate through the array again assigning that position (starting with the empty spot) the value in the next spot. When you get to the end of the array, just assign the last position, null.

Comment: Try using vector container that has erase method.

Comment: @Tracer I'm aware you could use vectors, but it's not the way I'm supposed to write this program.

Comment: Removing the second smallest should require only two iterations of your exchange-sort algorithm if you sort in reverse (end-to-front). It will also require you do something with the result of `Get_2nd_Smallest` besides ignore it, as right now you're just passing `0` to `Print_valid_data` function. After that, simply swap the last two elements and reduce the size by one. The resulting 0..orig_size-2 sequence will not include the smallest element, and end with the smallest element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may help, the *removal* is done by copying value over the previous one:

```
const int size = 6;
int v[] = {5, 6, 8, 2, 3, 1};

std::partial_sort(std::begin(v), std::begin(v) + 2, std::end(v));

std::cout << "The minimum number is: " << v[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << "The second smallest integer is: " << v[1] << std::endl;

std::copy(std::begin(v) + 2, std::end(v), std::begin(v) + 1);
std::cout << "remaining values: ";
for (int i = 0; i != size - 1; ++i) {
    std::cout << v[i] << ", ";
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/fGckmi)